# 'float' object is not subscriptable error

Tags: python

I got an error as title indicated.
And my script is attached as follows, the radius[i] is definitely a float, but why it cannot be accessed like this? How should I code?

```
import csv
import turtle

radius=[]
with open('D:/SURA/Archive/water-loss/output-sorption.csv') as loss_radius:
    reader = csv.reader(loss_radius,delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        radius.append(float(row[1]))

max=200
radius_max = 0.0
for i in range(200):
    radius_max = radius[i]
    radius = radius_max * (max - i) / max
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhgz2.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In last line of your code you overwrite radius variable from a list of floats to a single float value:

```
for i in range(200):
    radius_max = radius[i]
    radius = radius_max * (max - i) / max
```

Change the name of this last variable and it should be ok.

Comment: Oh god, I did not see that, hha. Thanks!